# select parent_id who have at least one boy and one girl

Tags: sql

Table: `parent_id, parent_name, child_id, child_gender`

How to list `parent_id` who have at least one boy and one girl.

Comment: School work? What have you tried this far? Show us the query and describe what's wrong with it!

Comment: you should specify some more info about table data ,so it will be help full to find out solution..

Comment: Actually, this is an interview question.

Comment: @RamboLi did you get the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Group by* the `parent_id` and take only those *having* children with at least 2 *distinct* genders

```
select parent_id
from your_table
group by parent_id
having count(distinct child_gender) = 2
```

Comment: Hopefully there are only two genders ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I guess a `WHERE child_gender IN ('M','F')` would solve that.

Comment: So smart! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

To get the parents that have a boy:

```
select parent_id from table where child_gender = 'M'
```

To get the parents that have a girl:

```
select parent_id from table where child_gender = 'F'
```

So to get the parents that are in both result sets:

```
select parent_id from table where child_gender = 'M'
intersect
select parent_id from table where child_gender = 'F'
```

Note: the two stand-alone queries can return duplicates, but `intersect` will make sure each parent appears at most once.

Comment: Yes it works. Never hear "intersect" before. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.parent_id -- , other columns
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.TableName t1
    WHERE t1.parent_id = t.parent_id AND t1. child_gender = 'M'
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.TableName t1
    WHERE t1.parent_id = t.parent_id AND t1. child_gender = 'F'
)
```

This isn't so concise but it has an advantage if you want all columns or the conditon is more complex.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from 
( 
select p1.*, count(pr_id) over(partition by pr_id) 
from PAIRENT_DETAILS p1  
group by p1.pr_id,p1.child_gender having count(p1.pr_id) = 1 
) as a 
where count = 2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As far as I understand the code, the inner select would find parents with exactly one boy and one girl. I highly doubt this code would work for the question.